# How to listen to a nested components' events in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-events

I want to get an "input" event from a nested component that I see firing from the Vue chrome devtools extension
[image]

I can only listen to the "input" event on the **VDatePicker** using the v-on directive. Is there a way to listen to the **VDatePickerDateTable** "input" event without extending the **VDatePicker** component?

```
<template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="selectedDays" multiple @input="onDayClick"/>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods:{
            onDateClick(data){
                console.log(data); // ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-06"]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.$on("eventName", callback)`? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on

Comment: That should work, see [this test](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/52c359939f91ccbd26c4b498f0ca8d2f20eef00b/packages/vuetify/test/unit/components/VDatePicker/VDatePicker.date.spec.js#L52)

Comment: This doesn't work it produces the same result.

Comment: @Matt and eric99 I think the reason your suggestion doesn't work is because of the **multiple** modifier which is new in [Vuetify 1.2](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I ended up doing. Using a ref to **VDatePicker** and following it into a nested ref of its child, **VDatePickerDateTable** to listen to its "input" event. The reason I think that the input on **VDatePicker** passes an array of date strings is because it is a multi date picker as defined by the **multiple** attribute on the component. This was added in [Vuetify 1.2](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers).

It now passes the date clicked to the handler. I would love to know if anyone has a better way.

```
<template>
    <v-date-picker ref="datePicker" v-model="selectedDays" multiple/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted(){
            this.$refs.datePicker.$refs.table.$on('input', this.onDayClick);
    },
    methods: {
        onDateClick(data) {
            console.log(data); // "2019-01-01"
        }
    }
};
</script>
```